# Copying looped data from one workbook and paste to another

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have written this code, and it works when doing it from one sheet to another. (Same workbook). But when i loop through the rows from workbook to workbook i get "Run time error 9" Subscript out of range.

I've checked several times if the filenames are as stated in the code, and it doesn't seem to be the problem. Also if I in the first piece write y.sheets("Tavledisplay") instead of worksheets("Tavledisplay") the debugger tells me there's a problem there. Doing it the latter way, it sends 1 loop of data, and stops at `y.sheets("Tavledisplay").Activate`.

My code:

```
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\u054939\Desktop\Diverse filer\Safecard\Safecardmaster.xlsm")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\u054939\Desktop\Diverse filer\Safecard\Tavleark1.xlsm")

    a = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To a

        If Worksheets("Tavledisplay").Cells(i, 14).Value = "Ja" Then
            Worksheets("Tavledisplay").Rows(i).Select
            Selection.Copy
            x.Sheets("Løsninger").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Løsninger").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            x.Sheets("Løsninger").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            y.Sheets("Tavledisplay").Activate
            Selection.ClearContents


    End If

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
x.Sheets("Løsninger").Select
```

I expect the code to loop through all the given rows, where there is a "Ja" in column 14, and pasting them into my other workbook sheet "Løsninger" and deleting them from the other workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop through each loop, a simple filter will do the trick:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\u054939\Desktop\Diverse filer\Safecard\Safecardmaster.xlsm")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\u054939\Desktop\Diverse filer\Safecard\Tavleark1.xlsm")

    'Look for the range to copy and set it
    With y.Worksheets("Tabledisplay")
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Ja"
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
        Set CopyRange = .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    'Paste it to the other sheet
    With x.Worksheets("Løsninger")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        CopyRange.Copy .Cells(LastRow, 1)
    End With

    'Delete the range from the original sheet
    CopyRange.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Doing this i still get "Subscript out of range error" at the "With x.worksheets("Løsninger") line. And also the code deleted everything else in my "Tavleark1" workbook and pasted the specific data into that range instead

Comment: @Nomadz94 the error may be because of that german O, you might want to change it. And about the second question, check if y must be x and viceversa... I did as I thought reading your code.

Comment: Hey Damian, what do you mean specifically by y must be x? It's been quite some time since I've last coded in VBA, so I'm currently quite a novice. I will also try without the "Ø"

Comment: @Nomadz94 you are giviing your workbooks a reference one is `x` and the other one is `y` (I would use `Sourcewb` and `Destwb` for example) maybe I switched which one is to copy and paste from.

Comment: My bad - I realized the autofilter just filters the blanks out, and does not delete them. The problems seems to appear at x.worksheets("Losninger"). Still giving me subscript out of range

Comment: What problems? on `x.worksheets("Losninger")` the procedure only calculates the last row and pastes the `CopyRange`and then deletes it.

Comment: The problem is run time error 9, it can't seem to identify either workbook or worksheet.

Comment: @Nomadz94 you can debug the value for the workbook name and check if the worksheet exists or whatever, you can go through your code pressing F8, vba will execute line per line.